# What mechanism does WordPress use to keep constants from being redefined?

Tags: constants

I recently posted a comment on a general tech group about this line of code:

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', true);
```

Someone replied, "If the original coders don't know that you can't redefine a constant than why would you even trust any of their other code?"

That made me wonder, what mechanism in WordPress keeps themes/plugins/etc from redefining constants? I'm guessing that it has to do with the order in which code loads.

Comment: Constants are controlled at the PHP level, not the WP level. If a plugin tries to redefine a constant, it will throw a PHP error. There's no WordPress-specific magic here.

Comment: So, the mechanism is PHP. Does that mean that there is no place in the WordPress core that defines WP_POST_REVISIONS? I recently ran across 2 sites that neither showed the Revisions list, nor had the option in Screen Options. I had to add the code in wp-config

Comment: WP defines the constant only if it is not already defined: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-constants.php#L366

Comment: Exactly the information I needed! If you would make this answer, I will check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What mechanism does WordPress use to keep constants from being redefined?

None. Constants are not a WordPress feature, they're a part of the PHP programming language.

> Someone replied, "If the original coders don't know that you can't redefine a constant than why would you even trust any of their other code?"

I think this is them suggesting that if the authors don't know that you cannot redefine a constant, then they might not be very good at PHP

> That made me wonder, what mechanism in WordPress keeps themes/plugins/etc from redefining constants? I'm guessing that it has to do with the order in which code loads.

Once a constant is defined, it can't be changed. PHP enforces this, otherwise constants would just be fancy variables that can change on a whim.

Generally, it's considered poor practice to define those constants in plugins and themes. They're intended for `wp-config.php` and should be set by the user. I would treat any plugin or theme that defines WP constants with great suspicion and skepticism.

Comment: Your GitHub reference says volumes. If it's not defined already, it will be defined in wp-includes.